# getMonth() function deprecated. What replaces it? Can't run my script anymore

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

For the past year I've had a script that has worked great. Essentially if today's date matches the dates in my sheets it send a reminder email. To do this I have used the getMonth() function. But recently I started getting emails from google that the script failed, looking into it, getMonth() has been deprecated. What replaces it? I can't find any threads online about it.

Essentially what I've been doing is taking a date in sheets and converting it to simple dd/mm/yyyy format. Sheets and scripts date functions pull time, so this formula removes that from the equation.

There is probably a work around of pulling a date and removing the non essential information, but this formula worked for me. Is there a new 'getMonth()' function? Or do I have a rewrite how I do things entirely.

```
firstDay= sheet.getRange(rowCount,2).getValue();
firstDay = (firstDay.getMonth()+1) + "/" + firstDay.getDate() + "/" + firstDay.getFullYear();
```

This is the formula that no longer works.

Comment: Where do you see getMonth() being depricated?  It's JavaScript

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It is unclear whether you want `M/d/yyyy`, `dd/MM/yyyy` or something else. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you wish to store a Date in a cell then you can just use setNumberFormat to whatever format you wish and let the spreadsheet do the formatting for you

Answer (score 0):

The [Date.getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) method has *not* been deprecated.

To convert a Date object to a text string in Google Apps Script, observing the correct timezone offset, use [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format), like this:

```js
  const date = sheet.getRange(rowCount, 2).getValue();
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(date) !== '[object Date]') {
    throw new Error(`The value '${date}' in row  ${rowCount} is not a date.`);
  }
  const timezone = sheet.getParent().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  const firstDay = Utilities.formatDate(value, timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Replace `yyyy-MM-dd` with your preferred date format.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDateString() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  sh.getRange("A1").setValue(new Date());
  Logger.log(sh.getRange("A1").setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").getDisplayValue());
}

Execution log
10:30:45 AM Notice  Execution started
10:30:46 AM Info    27/12/2022
10:30:47 AM Notice  Execution completed
```